# Rails I18n prepositions localization unpredictable results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

I have a small localization yaml file like this:

```
en:
  preposition:
    with: with
    on: on
```

and similar German locale. When I try to use `I18n.translate('preposition.on')` it produces unpredictable results and returns `true` instead of normal preposition. As far as I've understood while experimenting, Rails consider value `on` as `true` and opposite to `off`, but how should I deal with this if I really need just normal translation?

Comment: try add '': on: 'on'

Comment: Tried already. The only change is that in such case I get `translation missing en.preposition.on` and the same for German.

Comment: It seems that in YAML `on` has some specific meaning. However, key `on_the` also does not work :)

Comment: try restart server may be (it may be necessary if you add new i18n file)

Comment: restarted many times, cleared cache, but already found the solution and wrote it below. Those are really reserved words - both value and key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found here - http://juliankniephoff.wordpress.com/2012/09/01/reserved-words-in-yaml-and-translating-booleans-in-rails/

That says, that keys and values like `on`, `no`, `yes` are really YAML reserved words, so in order to make this work I had to change my locale file to this:

```
en:
  preposition:
    with: with
    "on": 'on'
```

That is to make key and value both look like strings.